# Python PyDash 'find' function returns Any instead of passed data type

Tags: python, python-typing, python-3.11, pydash

The logic in my case is much more complex, but here is what it boils down to.
I've got a list of dataclass instances.

```
import pydash as pyd

@dataclass
class Info:
    color: str
    taste: str

@dataclass
class Fruit:
    id: int
    name: str
    info: Info

fruits = [
    Fruit(1, 'apple', Info('red', 'sweet')),
    Fruit(2, 'orange', Info('orange', 'sour')),
    Fruit(3, 'banana', Info('yellow', 'sweet')),
]
```

Upon that list I'm conducting search.
When I access instance directly, attribute suggestions and type hints work.

```
first_fruit_color = fruits[0].info.color
#                                   ^^
#                          (variable) color: str
print(first_fruit_color) # red
```

But when I use PyDash's (it's like Lodash in JavaScript) 'find' method, it returns 'Any' type no matter what is passed inside.
So suggestions and type hints do not work at all.

```
orange_fruit = pyd.find(fruits, {'info': {'color': 'orange'}})
orange_fruit_name = orange_fruit.name if orange_fruit else None
#                                 ^^
#                          id: Any | Unknown
print(orange_fruit_name) # orange
```

Can it be fixed in a reasonable way or I should write my own search function?
Are there any better libraries for such things in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They haven not annotated their code, nor have they produced type stubs. Support for python typing was requested in [this issue](https://github.com/dgilland/pydash/issues/173) some time ago. I don't know about the progress on that.

This means that you will get (almost) no auto-suggestions form your IDE because basically no type inference is possible.

> Can it be fixed in a reasonable way [...]?

Depends on what you mean by *reasonable*.

If it is just the [`find`](https://pydash.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#pydash.collections.find) function you are interested in and maybe a few others, you can take the time to write your own wrappers for them with proper type annotations or at least with annotations/overloads that cover your use cases accurately.

I quickly threw together such a wrapper for `find` for you, just to demonstrate how this may look. The function is more complex than you might think at first glance, so I make no claims at all about these annotations being exhaustive. They should cover a few of the intended uses though and they definitely help with your particular example.

Here is the wrapper:

```py
from collections.abc import Callable, Collection, Hashable, Mapping
from typing import Optional, TypeVar, Union, overload

import pydash as pyd  # type: ignore[import]


K = TypeVar("K", bound=Hashable)
T = TypeVar("T")


@overload
def find(
    collection: Mapping[K, T],
    predicate: Optional[Callable[[T, K], bool]] = None,
) -> Optional[T]:
    ...


@overload
def find(
    collection: Collection[T],
    predicate: Union[
        Callable[[T], bool],
        Mapping[str, object],
        T,
        None,
    ] = None
) -> Optional[T]:
    ...


def find(
    collection: Collection[T],
    predicate: Union[
        Callable[[T, K], bool],
        Callable[[T], bool],
        Mapping[str, object],
        T,
        None,
    ] = None,
) -> Optional[T]:
    return pyd.find(collection, predicate=predicate)  # type: ignore[no-any-return]
```

Applied to your example code, this would like like this:

```py
...  # import the custom `find` function

from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class Info:
    color: str
    taste: str


@dataclass
class Fruit:
    id: int
    name: str
    info: Info


fruits = [
    Fruit(1, 'apple', Info('red', 'sweet')),
    Fruit(2, 'orange', Info('orange', 'sour')),
    Fruit(3, 'banana', Info('yellow', 'sweet')),
]

apple = find(fruits, {'info': Info('red', 'sweet')})
orange = find(fruits, {'info': {'color': 'orange'}})
banana = find(fruits, lambda fruit: fruit.id == 3)

reveal_type(apple)
reveal_type(orange)
reveal_type(banana)
```

Those `reveal_type` calls are for `mypy`.

Running `mypy` over this, I get `Revealed type is "Union[Fruit, None]"` in all three cases.

Note that the `pydash.find` function can never guarantee that the output will *not* be `None`, so you will still have to do the type narrowing (e.g. via `assert apple is not None` or `if orange is not None: ...`) to convince the type checker that you are definitely dealing with a `Fruit` instance.

Alternatively, you can of course make your wrapper raise an exception, if `pyd.find` returns `None`. Then you can annotate its return as `T` instead of `Optional[T]`. Depends on what behavior you want.

The first overload by the way covers the usage with a mapping such as a dictionary. In that case the predicate callable must accept a value and a key as arguments (in that order for some reason...). So you can also do something like this:

```py
a = {"x": 1, "y": 2, "z": 3}

def key_is_x(_val: object, key: Hashable) -> bool:
    return key == "x"

x = find(a, key_is_x)
reveal_type(x)  # builtins.int | None
```

Anyway, this probably only makes sense, if you are using *just a few* pydash functions in *a lot of places* in your code. Otherwise the cost-benefit-ratio is probably not great.